# How to make an arrow pointing down with CSS (with gradient)?

Tags: html, css, gradient, css-shapes

Through some examples I found online, I figured out to make an "up" HTML arrow using

```
.arrow:after {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.upArrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #000);
}
```

My quesiton is, how do I make the down arrow? 
 My Fiddle illustrating this is here -- https://jsfiddle.net/hsfm42mb/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your down arrow css be

```
.downArrow:after {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
    linear-gradient(-120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%),
    linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same style of the up arrow for the down arrow, and rotate it 180 degrees:

```css
.arrow:after {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.upArrow:after, .downArrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #000);
}

.downArrow:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="upArrow" class="upArrow arrow"></div>
<br />
<div id="downArrow" class="downArrow arrow"></div>
```